# What is the biggest number you can make with 6 9s?

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle, formation-of-numbers

What is the biggest number you can make with 6 9s?

These are the allowed operators:

1. Subtraction
2. Addition
3. Multiplication
4. Division
5. Factorial
6. Exponents
7. Square root
8. Floor and Ceiling functions
9. Arbitrary root

You can use up to 20 operators.

Those are the rules - Have fun!

Comment: Are you aware of a provably optimal solution?

Comment: Yes. I really messed up on this question, didn't i? I tried to do another question because i haven't posted one in at least a week and just left it like that because i like asking math question and seeing the awesome and gigantic answers, not to ruin my reputation. Honestly, i blame myself.

Comment: @one23456789 In fact, you earned more reputation than you lost with this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\left(\left(\left(\left(\left(\left(\left(\left(\left(\left(\left(\left(\left(\left(\left(9^{\left(9^{\left(9^{\left(9^{\left(9^{9}\right)}\right)}\right)}\right)}\right)!\right)!\right)!\right)!\right)!\right)!\right)!\right)!\right)!\right)!\right)!\right)!\right)!\right)!\right)!$$

Or perhaps:

$$9^{\left(9^{\left(9^{\left(9^{\left(9^{\left(\left(\left(\left(\left(\left(\left(\left(\left(\left(\left(\left(\left(\left(9!\right)!\right)!\right)!\right)!\right)!\right)!\right)!\right)!\right)!\right)!\right)!\right)!\right)!\right)!}\right)}\right)}\right)}\right)}$$

I.e. Use 5 exponents and 15 factorials.

Comment: Hmm... $9^{9!}>(9^9)!$

Comment: @DanielMathias Not true. For example, taking the log of both terms gives log(9) x 9!  and, using Stirling's approximation, 9^9 x (9 log(9) - 1) .

Comment: @loopywalt Yeah, it's not even close. I'm not sure what I was thinking. Some careful coding gives $9^{9!}\approx 3.325\times 10^{346275}\approx 200\times 77706!$, which is obviously *much* less than $387420489!$